# Movie about a robbery by moving a building

Tags: identify-this-movie

I'm looking for a movie from about the early 2000s or late '90s. The only real part I remember is in relation to a robbery. The robbery I believe was in Venice (as can be deduced from below), the robbers wish to gain access to the house which has laser or some light beam security. They cannot redirect the beam because the angle they have through the window misses the target. They end up bypassing it by raising the building by putting airbags under the foundation columns which are under water (hence Venice) which gives them the correct angle to bypass the security. I cannot remember where this occurs within the movie, i.e. weather it is stretched across the whole movie or just the opening scene.  I do think the movie is about robbery, like the Italian Job or Entrapment.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I am 99% sure that the movie you are describing is [Oceans 12](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0349903/) with George Clooney, Brad Pitt et al.  You've almost perfectly described their attempted robbery of a building where they need to raise the building to fire something through a window to disable security.

This is their first attempt to raise the cash to pay off Terry Benedict, and occurs early in the movie.

Oh, and the building is in Amsterdam ... but since that is a city with a large network of canals, this is not inconsistent with your description.

Comment: That's it, Thanks. I never even thought of Oceans, I own a copy and everything.

Answer (score -2):

Easily miscontrued as The Italian Job, where they stole a safe by cutting a hole in the floor and having it land in a boat.  That movie did take place in Venice, so you may have combined a few facts about the two movies in your mind.  But, as iandotkelly pointed out, it was most likely Oceans 12.